# Chart.js displaying each letter of label and data as a single value on chart. The data and labels provided are arrays

Tags: arrays, charts, chart.js, label, ejs

I am using Chart.js to make a line chart. The working of the code is as follows. (Snapshots of the code below)

- Data is retrieved from MongoDB and then the array of numerical data is passed to ejs file.
- In the ejs file, when individual elements of the retrieved data are passes on to the data array, then it works correctly but not when whole array is passed.

The graph should look like this:

(There are total 30 values but only 5 are passed for sample)

[image: Desired Result]

But when I pass the whole array to data, then this happens:

[image: Incorrect Result]

The relevent code is as follows.

First code is (Using express and the data for graph is in "prices". It is an array as I have confirmed it multiple times.Also the individual tag is use for something else and is not neccesary for the chart.)

```html
app.get('/:symb', async (req, res) => { const { symb } = req.params;

let prices = await (await price.find({ Symbol: symb }).distinct("Data.Close")).slice(-30);



res.render('individual.ejs', { prices, individual });
```

Second code is (using ejs)

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script>

            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: `<%=base %>`,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: `<%= prices %>`,
                        backgroundColor: 'green', options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true

                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }

                    }]
                }
            });
```

(Here the labels "base" is an array of string from 1 to 30 ['1','2','3'...] and is just the count of main data "prices".

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem is that you convert your labels array to a string by surrounding it by backticks. Chart.js does not like this. If you remove the backticks around the labels array variable and also around the data variable it should work fine

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCHH!! THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED BY CONVERTING THE STRING TO ARRAY USING string.split.